# Struct packing and alignment with mingw

Tags: c, arm, mingw32, stm32

I am emulating code from an embedded system (stm32, Keil µVision 5, MDK-ARM) on a PC (mingw32, 32bit arch). The alignment of the ARM compiler does not match my desktop *mingw* build:

```
// ARM Code (ARM compiler uses __packed)
typedef __packed struct _file
{
    uint8_t var1;
    uint16_t var2;
} FILE;

// PC mingw gcc code trying to emulate layout above.
typedef struct __attribute__((packed, aligned(1))) _file
{
    uint8_t var1;
    uint16_t var2;
} FILE;
```

In the source I do the following: `file.var1 = 0x22; file.var2 = 0xAA55;` which is then written to memory. When I read the memory on the embedded system it shows `0x22, 0x55, 0xAA`.  On the Windows machine it reads `0x22, 0xFF, 0x55, 0xAA`, with padding at the 2<sup>nd</sup> byte.  How can I correct this behaviour?

Comment: OT: I'd suggest using a different name than `FILE`, that name is defined by the standard library and it's possible that any standard header you include in the Windows environment will also include `stdio.h`, even if the embedded environment doesn't have it

Comment: haha yes, you are right but this is not the code I am actually using. To demonstrate the behaviour I changed the names and trimmed it down.

Comment: you are misunderstanding and misusing the language is the problem.  implementation defined features are just that.  No reason to expect them to work that way beyond that one implementation that one day/version...

Answer (score 6):

I fixed it by myself -> Compiling with -mno-ms-bitfields helps! The code above is indeed correct. It is necessary to tell mingw to use gcc's bitfield organisation instead of the microsoft style. Though the code can be uncompileable with microsoft compilers then, I do not care at this point.

Comment: Alright? There are no bitfields in the code, but perhaps the compiler is being prepared for some.

Comment: I guess it is a problem in the mingw implementation.

Comment: This [old gcc post](https://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/mingw/2008-November/000083.html) explains what it is doing.  The question is not very clear.  It sounded like you are porting PC code to an ARM; not the other way around.  Normally, *cygwin* wants to be compatible with the Windows way.  Ie, your code is expected to do Windows things with DLLs, etc and not try to *emulate* an ARM.  I think I would look into XEN, etc to actually emulate this slow ARM CPU.

Comment: Ie, the [`gcc_struct`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.0/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html) is probably the better option.  See section **6.36.5 i386 Variable Attributes**.  If you call actual Windows code, you may need the other one.

Comment: I can't find documentation on `-mno-ms-bitfields` anywhere in GCC doc. 
Any URL link to that ?

Comment: The gcc struct link above is to an older version of the documentation referring to "i386". The current version, referring to "x86", can be found [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Variable-Attributes.html).

Checking [this list](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html) of architectures with specific attributes, there's no separate entry for x86-64, so the information probably applies to 64-bit as well as 32-bit Windows/processor setups.

Comment: @LAL The gcc docs have information on `-mno-ms-bitfields` and `-mms-bitfields` [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Options.html#x86-Options).

Answer (score 3):

attribute packed is [broken on mingw32 compilers](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52991). Another option is to use
[pragma pack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/pack?view=msvc-170):

```
#pragma pack(1)
typedef struct _file
{
  uint8_t var1;
  uint16_t var2;
} FILE;
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [the GCC manual's examples](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.1/gcc/Type-Attributes.html), the `attribute` should go after the struct's fields, i.e.:

```
// PC Code
typedef struct
{
    uint8_t var1;
    uint16_t var2;
} __attribute__((packed, aligned(1))) FILE;
```

I also dropped the pointless struct tag (`_file`).

The above has a `sizeof` value of `3` when I tested it quickly.

Comment: `warning: 'packed' attribute ignored [-Wattributes]
 }  FILE __attribute__((packed, aligned(1)));` Hmmmm..

Comment: @artlessnoise What is not a `typedef`? The OP's code shows two `typedef`s, right?

Comment: @unwind Actually, according to [the GCC manual's page on attribute syntax](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Attribute-Syntax.html) both placements of `attribute` are valid: *"An attribute specifier list may appear as part of a struct, union or enum specifier. It may go either immediately after the struct, union or enum keyword, or after the closing brace. The former syntax is preferred."*

Comment: Plus, the link to GCC type attribute documentation in your answer is now outdated. [The current version](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Type-Attributes.html) places `attribute` after `struct` in the examples, instead of after `}`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add gcc_struct attribute to tell mingw which struct packing alghorithm to use:
**attribute**((**gcc_struct**,**packed**));

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Thank you for your answer. Would you mind explaining more completely how to use this attribute and where to apply it?