# Troubles while reading the struct size

Tags: c

If I debug the following code then I see the `size` value is 12 (as expected).

```
#include <cstdint>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    typedef struct __attribute__((__packed__))  { int8_t value; } time;

    typedef struct __attribute__((__packed__))  {
        uint8_t msg[8];
//        time t1;
        uint32_t count;
    } theStruct;

    theStruct s;
    int size = sizeof(s);

    return 0;
}
```

Interestingly, removing the comment at "time t1;", the value of `size` goes to 16. I was expecting  13.

I know (more or less) that this is explained by the data structure padding story...

But, is there some way to avoid this issue?
What to do in order to read `size = 13`?

Comment: In my test (g++ 4.8.4) I get a size of `13` with the comment removed. Are you sure you tested it correctly?

Comment: Yes, typed correctly. I'm using (Qt enviroment x86) MinGW 4.8.2 32 bit

Comment: I can reproduce @EvanTeran's results.  BTW, what's your programming language?  C or C++?  How do you invoke the compiler?

Comment: I'm using Qt 5.3.2. To invoke the compiler just push play... May I provide more details?

Comment: deleted my comment, gcc documentation says: "You may also specify any one of these attributes with '_\_' preceding and following its keyword.  This allows you to use these attributes in header files without being concerned about a possible macro of the same name.  For example, you may use '_\_aligned_\_' instead of 'aligned'."

Comment: What `sizof(time)` is giving?

Comment: Also, why is `time` a struct? if it has only one member? just for syntax?

Comment: Is there something that will make the compiler ignore `__attribute__((__packed__))`?

Comment: Can't reproduce it as well..Look at the `map` file.

Comment: @iharob, just to exemply here.

Comment: sizeof() returns a size_t, not an int.

Comment: @KcFnMi does it happen if you do this `#pragma pack(1) typedef struct { int8_t value; } time; typedef struct { int8_t t1;  uint32_t count; uint8_t msg[8]; } theStruct; #pragma pack(1)`?

Comment: Just check if it is packing, say, a structure containing an array of 3 bytes, for example.

Comment: @iharob, problem solved. Now I see 13. May I ask for some explanation?

Comment: `#pragma` is a different way of declaring these attributes in other compilers.. I wonder why it is working here for gcc..

Comment: @KcFnMi the `__attribute__`  thing is `gcc` specific and it might be causing problems on MinGW.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some issues with MinGW's emulation of [MSVC struct packing](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52991).

The workaround is to pass `-mno-ms-bitfields` flag to the compiler; this will cause it to use its own layout algorithm rather than attempt to emulate MSVC.

See also [Struct packing and alignment with mingw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24015852/struct-packing-and-alignment-with-mingw) (ARM but may be the same issue).

Comment: That's what I thought it had to do with the OS because on my Linux system it didn't happen. And that was why [I suggested what's in my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31480287/troubles-while-reading-the-struct-size?noredirect=1#comment50926597_31480287) which you can append to this answer if you like.

Answer (score 0):

It is clearly an alignement problem, meaning it has nothing to do with the language itself but all with the underlying platform.

If the platform knows (or thinks) that `int32_t` need an alignement of 4, it should add 3 bytes of padding after time.

Anyway `__attribute__((__packed__))` is non standard C and will only be interpreted by gcc (*). Worse it leads to non portable programs : according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8568441/3545273) on another question, it would cause a bus error on a Sparc architecture because of a misaligned int32_t.

I do know that x86 (and derivatives) architecture are now the most common, but other architecture may still exist ...

(*) according to [Visual C++ equivalent of GCC's __attribute__ ((__packed__))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537964/visual-c-equivalent-of-gccs-attribute-packed), the MSVC equivalent is `#pragma pack(push, 1)`