# fread(): Reading from a file (without alignment) results in skipping of bytes

Tags: c, struct, byte, fread, struct-member-alignment

I have a file and using C I want to read the contents of it using fread() (from stdio.h) and write it into the members of a struct. (In my case there is a 2 byte int at the start followed by a 4 byte int.)
But after writing the contents of the file correctly into the first two byte variable of the struct, it skips two bytes before continuing with the second four byte variable.

To demonstrate, I have created a 16 byte file to read from. In Hex it looks like this (Little-endian):
`22 11 66 55 44 33 11 11  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00`

With the following code I expect the first variable, `twobytes`, to be `0x1122` and the second, `fourbytes`, to be `0x33445566`. But instead it prints:

```
twobytes: 0x1122 
fourbytes: 0x11113344

sizeof(FOO) = 8
&foo     : 0061FF14
&foo.two : 0061FF14
&foo.four: 0061FF18
```

Skipping bytes 3 and 4 (`0x66` & `0x55`). Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void) {

    FILE* file = fopen("216543110.txt", "r");
    if (file==NULL) { return 1; }

    typedef struct
    {
        uint16_t twobytes;
        uint32_t fourbytes;
    }__attribute__((__packed__)) // removing this attribute or just the underscores around packed does not change the outcome
    FOO;
    
    FOO foo;
    
    fread(&foo, sizeof(FOO), 1, file);
    
    printf("twobytes: 0x%x \n", foo.twobytes);
    printf("fourbytes: 0x%x \n\n", foo.fourbytes);

    printf("sizeof(FOO) = %d\n", sizeof(FOO));
    printf("&foo     : %p\n", &foo);
    printf("&foo.two : %p\n", &foo.twobytes);
    printf("&foo.four: %p\n", &foo.fourbytes);
    
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Using a struct with two same size integers works as expected.

---

So: Using fread() to write into different size variables causes skipping bytes:

**`22 11`** *`.. ..`* **`44 33 11 11`** *`...`*

instead of

**`22 11` `66 55 44 33`** *`...`*

---

I am aware that something about byte alignment is playing a role here, but how does that affect the *reading* of bytes? If C wants to add padding to the structs, how does that affect the reading from a file?
I don't care if C is storing the struct members as
**`22 11`** *`.. ..`* **`66 55 44 33`** *`...`*
or
**`22 11` `66 55 44 33`** *`...`*,
I'm confused about why it fails to read my file correctly.

Also, I am using `gcc version 6.3.0 (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1)`

Comment: if sizeof struct is 8 bytes then it reads 8 bytes.

Comment: You should check/print the value of `sizeof(FOO)`, which appears to be 8 bytes in your code, with the two 'missing' bytes added as padding between the two structure members. I think you need to apply the `__attribute__((__packed__))` to **individual members** of the structure.

Comment: @Adrian Mole, According to [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.0.2/gcc/Type-Attributes.html), it can be used on the struct too. But it shows it before the curlies. Of course, that could be for a different compiler or compiler version than the OP is using

Comment: @Paul Tashkent, Since you're asking about a non-standard compiler extension, you should mention the compiler and its version

Comment: Please add the following lines to your program and tell us the output: 1. `printf( "%d\n", sizeof(FOO) );` 2. `printf( "%p\n", &foo );` 3. `printf( "%p\n", &foo.twobytes );` 4. `printf( "%p\n", &foo.fourbytes );`

Comment: Try `__attribute__((packed))` instead of `__attribute__((__packed__))` and I'm surprised you don't get a warning about an unknown attribute.

Comment: When I [run the code on OnlineGDB](https://onlinegdb.com/rycSfWPxD), I get `sizeof(FOO) == 6` with `__attribute__((__packed__))` and `sizeof(FOO) == 8` without it. OnlineGDB uses the gcc compiler.

Comment: I think 'twobytes' variable might be aligned to 4 bytes. Then when you try to read 8 bytes  in total -  2 'lost' bytes are in 2 bytes between 'twobytes' and 'fourbytes' variable. Can you print all 8 bytes separately in that struct ?

Comment: @Marcin: Yes, that alignment is the default behavior. The point of `__attribute__((__packed__))` is to override this default behavior.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Added the Information you requested. `sizeof(FOO)` is indeed `8`. But my question of why it "skips" those bytes while *reading* does not feel answered yet.
@ikegami Added my compiler version as well.

Comment: @PaulTashkent, there is no reason to think that `fread()` skips any bytes.  The issue is *where it puts* the bytes it reads, and how that relates to the `twobytes` and `fourbytes` members of your `struct`.  If you don't see the expected bytes in either of those members, then the only likely answer is that they go into padding bytes in the struct between those two members.  Why your compiler accepts `__attribute__((__packed__))` yet still lays out the structure with padding is a different question.

Comment: Now that you are now also printing `&foo.fourbytes`, you can see that this address is 4 bytes apart from `&foo.twobytes`, so there must be two bytes of padding. This is very useful information.

Comment: @JohnBollinger So basically all boils down to my compiler being weird...?

Comment: @PaulTashkent, there *is* some kind of compiler weirdness going on, but please don't take it the wrong way that I attribute the problem to relying on language extensions in the first place.

Comment: @PaulTashkent: As pointed out in the answer, you may also want to try to change the position of `__attribute__ ((__packed__))`.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I did try to reposition the attribute where ever I could. For example even sepereting `typedef` from the `struct` decleration itself didn't help either

Comment: Hmmm, I [tested it with gcc version 6.3 on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/7ecT7o), and it works as it should. Are you using any special compiler options?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Not that I'd know. I've set everything up a few years ago without using it until now. I may try reinstalling everything C related and actually look into what I'm doing over the next few days...

Comment: @PaulTashkent: I don't think that the problem is your compiler being old, because even if I set the compiler to gcc version 5.1 on godbolt (link see above), it still works.

Comment: @PaulTashkent: do you have options such as `-ansi` or `-std=c99`?

Comment: @PaulTashkent: I can reproduce your problem, but it takes a `"-D__attribute__(x)="` command line option, which would be a very vicious thing to hide in a Makefile

Comment: @AndreasWenzel @chqrlie The console in my IDE says:
`gcc -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/fread.d" -MT"src/fread.o" -o "src/fread.o" "../src/fread.c"`

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31622291/12149471) sounds interesting. Especially #2 of the answer. Also, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24016239/12149471) might be interesting, recommends using the `-mno-ms-bitfields` command-line option in the compiler. In a comment, someone also recommends using [`gcc_struct`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.0/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html).

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37199319/12149471) is also interesting, which recommend using [`#pragma pack`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/2e70t5y1) instead.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Yes! `#pragma pack()` works for me. Thank you for finding and posting that answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On GCC, when targetting x86 platforms, the

`__attribute__((__packed__))`

only works on structs with

[`__attribute__((gcc_struct))`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-10.2.0/gcc/x86-Type-Attributes.html).

However, when targetting Microsoft Windows platforms, the default attribute for structs is

`__attribute__((ms_struct))`.

Therefore, I see three ways to accomplish what you want:

1. Use the compiler command-line option [`-mno-ms-bitfields`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-10.2.0/gcc/x86-Options.html) to make all structs default to `__attribute__((gcc_struct))`.
2. Explicitly use `__attribute__((gcc_struct))` on your struct.
3. Use [`#pragma pack`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/2e70t5y1) instead of `__attribute__((__packed__))`.

Also, as pointed out in the answer by @chqrlie, there are some other things not ideal in your code. Especially when reading binary data, you should normally open the file in binary mode and not text mode, unless you know what you are doing (which you possibly are, since the file has a `.txt` extension).

Answer (score 3):

From the output your program produces, it seems the compiler ignores the `__attribute__(__packed__)` specification.

The [gcc online user's guide](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.0.2/gcc/Type-Attributes.html) documents the `__attribute__ ((__packed__))` type attribute with an example where this attribute is placed before the `{` of the definition.

This extension is non standard so it is possible that different compilers or different versions of any given compiler handle it differently depending on the placement choice. If you use gcc, moving the attribute should fix the problem. If you use a different compiler, look at the documentation to figure what it does differently.

Also note these remarks:

- the file should be opened in binary mode, with `"rb"`,
- the `sizeof(FOO)` argument should be cast as `(int)` for the `%d` conversion specifier.
- pointer arguments for `%p` should be cast as `(void *)`.
- `foo.twobytes` has the same address as `foo`, which is mandated by the C Standard and `&foo.fourbytes` is located 4 bytes away, which means `foo.fourbytes` is aligned and there are 2 padding bytes between the 2 members.

Try modifying your code this way:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *file = fopen("216543110.txt", "rb");
    if (file == NULL) {
        return 1;
    }

    typedef struct __attribute__((__packed__)) {
        uint16_t twobytes;
        uint32_t fourbytes;
    } FOO;
    
    FOO foo;
    
    if (fread(&foo, sizeof(FOO), 1, file) == 1) {
        printf("twobytes : 0x%x\n", foo.twobytes);
        printf("fourbytes: 0x%x\n\n", foo.fourbytes);

        printf("sizeof(FOO) = %d\n", (int)sizeof(FOO));
        printf("&foo     : %p\n", (void *)&foo);
        printf("&foo.two : %p\n", (void *)&foo.twobytes);
        printf("&foo.four: %p\n", (void *)&foo.fourbytes);
    }
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Although your answer is good and I have upvoted it, I would like to point out that the main problem was something different: The `__attribute__((__packed__))` has no effect on structs with `__attribute__((ms_struct))`, which is the default when targetting the Microsoft Windows x86 platform. See my answer for more information.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel: excellent point! Sorry I missed your latest comments... So much time has been wasted for decades dealing with the quirks and pitfalls of MS legacy platforms... More money gone down the drain than even the market value of this company(!)

Answer (score 1):

Since the data structure in memory is different from one in file, It may be better to read the members of struct one by one.
For example, there are a way to specify position to read  the members of struct with "offsetof".
The following reads the members of struct with the fread_members function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h> /* offsetof */

/* offset and size of each member */
typedef struct {
    size_t offset;
    size_t size;
} MEMBER;

#define MEMBER_ELM(type, member) {offsetof(type, member), sizeof(((type*)NULL)->member)}

size_t fread_members(void *ptr, MEMBER *members, FILE *stream) {
    char *top = (char *)ptr;
    size_t rs = 0;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; members[i].size > 0; i++){
        rs += fread(top + members[i].offset, 1, members[i].size, stream);
    }
    return rs;
}

int main(void) {

    FILE* file = fopen("216543110.txt", "r");
    if (file==NULL) { return 1; }

    typedef struct
    {
        uint16_t twobytes;
        uint32_t fourbytes;
    } FOO;

    MEMBER members[] = {
        MEMBER_ELM(FOO, twobytes),
        MEMBER_ELM(FOO, fourbytes),
        {0, 0} /* terminated */
    };

    FOO foo;

    fread_members(&foo, members, file);

    :
```

Comment: Yes, this is a good workaround, so I have upvoted it. However, it still only is a workaround, not a solution to the underlying problem. See my answer for the solution to the underlying problem.

Comment: Your answer is direct, certain, easy and great to this question.
However, if the data structure and its struct is not closed in a function, the alignment problem have to solve somewhere in the program, copying to another struct/array instance, porting to other platforms, accessing members without SIGBUS, etc.