# Strange byte alignment between windows and Linux gcc compiler

Tags: linux, gcc, mingw, fread, struct-member-alignment

I see a strange behavior of reading a bin file and mapping in to the structure in the windows compared to linux gcc compiler.

Below is my c code:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define IV_MAX_LEN              32
#define HASH_MAX_LEN            64
#define MAX_NUM_IMGS            8
#define MAX_NUM_SRK_RECORDS     4
#define SKIP_OFFSET_1K          0x400

typedef struct {
    uint8_t version;
    uint16_t length;
    uint8_t tag;
    uint16_t srk_table_offset;
    uint16_t cert_offset;
    uint16_t blob_offset;
    uint16_t signature_offset;
    uint32_t reserved;
} __attribute__((packed)) blk_hdr_t;

typedef struct {
    uint32_t offset;
    uint32_t size;
    uint64_t dst;
    uint64_t entry;
    uint32_t hab_flags;
    uint32_t meta;
    uint8_t hash[HASH_MAX_LEN];
    uint8_t iv[IV_MAX_LEN];
} __attribute__((packed)) boot_t;
typedef struct {
    uint8_t version;
    uint16_t length;
    uint8_t tag;
    uint32_t flags;
    uint16_t sw_version;
    uint8_t fuse_version;
    uint8_t num_images;
    uint16_t sig_blk_offset;
    uint16_t reserved;
    boot_t img[MAX_NUM_IMGS];
    blk_hdr_t blk_hdr;
    uint32_t sigblk_size;
    uint32_t padding;
} __attribute__((packed)) headerMain_t;

int main()
{
    int ofd =1;
    char filename[] = "sample.bin";
    int readSizes= 0;
    int headerSizes= 0;
    headerMain_t header;
    uint8_t *byte;

    ofd = open(filename, O_RDONLY);
    printf("\nOPENING File: %s!\n", filename);
    printf("\n STRUCT sizes: %d, %d, %d,\n", sizeof(headerMain_t), sizeof(boot_t), sizeof(blk_hdr_t));
#if 0
    if(lseek(ofd, SKIP_OFFSET_1K, SEEK_SET) < 0) {
        printf("Error Read \n");
    }
#endif    
    readSizes = read(ofd, &header, sizeof(header)) ;
    headerSizes = sizeof(header);
    printf("\n Read SIZE: %d / %d !",readSizes,headerSizes);
    
    printf("\n Read Bytes: \n");
    byte = (uint8_t*)&header;
    for(int i=0; i<readSizes; i++)
    {
        printf("0x%02x, ",*byte);
        byte++;
        if(0 ==i%20 )
            printf("\n");
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

and here is the input [binary file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PgAyKpFBk5aHY-sKZqF5L6Vcp3MhYwr0/view?usp=sharing) it reads. (This sample bin file is *0x01 (20 times)... 0xFF(20 times)* = so **255 x 20 = 5100 bytes**)
The same code is compiled and run in windows mingW-gcc and linux gcc.

Following are the strange observations seen in the windows run:
[image]

1. `blk_hdr_t` struct although 4 byte aligned  and 16 bytes it total: 22 bytes
   (*Update*: I found that this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24016239/1153916) worked with -mno-ms-bitfields option)
2. Although 5100 bytes are available, read() function could read only 1000 bytes. what choked it further to read ?
3. read() also puts the "holes" with "0x00" bytes value in it. I don't understand this strange behaviour.
4. Enabling the lseek to skip first 1024 bytes shall reach the end of the file.

**Everything looks perfect on the linux result** (although point 3) does exist on the linux side too: although this is trivial for me, i'm curious on the behaviour)

so finally, How can make this code on windows gcc with the **Exact result** as in the linux gcc ?
could anyone please enlighten me ?
(The parameters in the structures cannot be reshuffled)

Comment: Try opening the file in binary mode, like: `open(filename, O_RDONLY | O_BINARY)`